# OOP approach to objects with many flavours

Tags: python, class, object, oop, abstraction

I've been writing code to parse and extract information from messages sent by a bot. There are only a few different kinds of messages, but each one of them contains wildly different kinds of information I'm interested in, and I'm struggling with finding the best way to deal with them as objects in my code.

If I were using Haskell, I'd simply create a type `Message` and define a tailored constructor for each kind of message

```
data Message = Greeting Foo Bar | Warning Yadda Yadda Yadda | ...
```

It's a very nice and clean way to both have them all under the same `type` and be able to tell the message kinds apart easily.

How would one go about designing object classes to that effect in a OOP-friendly (or better, pythonic) way?
I've thought of two approaches, namely:

- Defining a base-class `Message` and subclassing it for each kind of message. **Pros:** conceptually clean. **Cons:** lots of boilerplate code, and it doesn't really make the code very readable or the relationship between different message classes clear.
- Defining a universal class `Message`, which represents every message type. It will have an attribute `.type` to differentiate between message kinds, and its `__init__` function will instantiate the attributes appropriate to the message type accordingly. **Pros:** Simple to code, practical. **Cons:** it seems a bad practice to have the class' attributes be so unpredictable, and it generally feels wrong.

but I'm not completely satisfied with neither. While I realize that this is a just small programme, I'm using it as an opportunity to learn more about the use of abstractions and software architecture, I suppose. Can someone show me the way?

Comment: Either option is probably fine, but the second seems like the light er approach. You could define a [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) to give you more control over the potential message types while keeping the classes descriptive

Comment: Make a simple [mcve] with a couple of strings and how you plan to use them.

Comment: Have you considered Python dataclasses? Those should give you clean code without much boilerplate.

Comment: @joshmeranda thank you for weighting in! I was leaning towards the first approach myself, but this `enum` indexing is indeed interesting

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you for the reply! As I see it, my question is more general in nature and I wouldn't like it to rely too much on implementation details. I'm afraid adding this additional information would muddy the waters, so to speak, but I wouldn't mind sharing it if you believe it you be helpful.

Comment: @David Perhaps the base class `Message` could be implemented as a dataclass, and then its subclasses would inherit all the goodies, thanks for the suggestion. What I was looking for, however, was for a more general approach, or at least best-practices, when presented with situations such as this one

Comment: @impresso. Programming is a tool to solve problems. There are many approaches possible, and the choice is always very case-specific. Trying to apply general rules to specific situations will often land you in trouble. In integer words, the only real best practice is to use your common sense.

Comment: In this particular case, I'd argue that it very much matters how you plan to use the data. If there's a message specific processing that happens, at it to a separate class, if you're just recording the data, I'd treat it differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a message class design, I'd use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to minimise the boilerplate. You get to focus entirely on the fields:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Message:
    # common message methods

@dataclass
class Greeting(Message):
    foo: str
    bar: int

@dataclass
class Warning(Message):
    yadda: list[str]
```

There usually isn't much more you need for a simple project. You could add a `@classmethod` factory to the `Message` base class to help generating specific message types, and `Message` could be a `@dataclass` itself too, if there are common attributes shared between the different types.

That said, once you start to factor in serialisation and deserialisation requirements, using a `type` field that is an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) *can* be helpful.

To illustrate that point: For a current RESTFul API project that includes automated OpenAPI 3.1 documentation, we are using [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to handle translation from and to JSON, [marshmallow-dataclasses](https://pypi.org/project/marshmallow-dataclass/) to avoid having to repeat ourselves to define the schema and validation, and [marshmallow-oneofschema](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-oneofschema) to reflect a polymorphic schema for a hierarchy of classes that differ by their type much like your `Message` example.

Using 3rd-party libraries then constrains your options, so I used metaprogramming (mostly [`class.__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) and [`Generic` type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types)) to make it possible to concisely define such a polymorphic type hierachy that's keyed on an enum.

Your message type would be expressed like this:

```
class MessageType(enum.Enum):
    greeting = "greeting"
    warning = "warning"
    # ...

@dataclass
class _BaseMessage(PolymorphicType[MessageType]):
    type: MessageType
    # ...

@dataclass
class Greeting(_BaseMessage, type_key=MessageType.greeting):
    foo: str
    bar: int

@dataclass
class Warning(_BaseMessage, type_key=MessageType.warning):
    yadda: list[str]

MessageSchema = _BaseMessage.OneOfSchema("MessageSchema")
```

after which messages are loaded from JSON using `MessageSchema.load()`, producing a specific instance based on the `"type"` key in the dictionary, e.g.

```
message = MessageSchema.load({"type": "greeting", "foo": "spam", "bar": 42})
isinstance(message, Greeting)  # True
```

while `MessageSchema.dump()` gets you suitable JSON output regardless of the input type:

```
message = Warning([42, 117])
MessageSchema.dump(message)  # {"type": "warning", "yadda": [42, 117]}
```

It is the use of an `enum` here that makes the integration work best; `PolymorphicType` is the custom class that handles most of the heavy lifting to make the `_BaseMessage.OneOfSchema()` call at the end work. You don't *have* to use metaprogramming to achieve that last part, but for us it reduced removed most of the `marshmallow-oneschema` boilerplate.

Plus, we get OpenAPI schemas that reflect each specific message type, which documentation tools like [Redocly](https://redoc.ly/docs/resources/discriminator/) know how to process:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Message:
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Greeting'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Warning'
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
        mapping:
          greeting: '#/components/schemas/Greeting'
          warning: '#/components/schemas/Warning'
    Greeting:
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          default: greeting
        foo:
          type: string
        bar:
          type: integer
    Warning:
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          default: warning
        yadda:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for the detailed answer; it was quite in line with what @David had said. I'm accepting it while I mull over the suggestions you've presented in the second half, cheers!